# If $f(x)$ is strictly convex, then is $g(x,y)=f(x + y)$ also strictly convex?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Assume that function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly convex.
Next, let $g(x,y): \mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $g(x,y) = f(x+y)$.

The question: is $g$ a strictly convex function?

I am confused here. Strictly convex function has unique minimum. Assume $f = (a - x)^{2}$. Then, $g(x,y) = (a - x - y)^2$, but the minimum of $g$ is not unique, cause the minimum is $x+y = a$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Is it true that a strictly convex function has a unique minimum point? What about $f(x) = e^x$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: But *if* a strictly convex function has a local minimum (as in $f(x) = (a-x)^2$) then that is a (unique) global minimum.

Comment: Your example shows that $g$ may not be *strictly* convex, since $g$ is constant on lines $x+y= c$.

Comment: I agree, this is why I asked the question. Therefore, the statement is wrong, right?

Comment: Also, I forgot that strictly convex function has unique minimum is it is coercive.

Comment: It may not have global minimum, at most one

Comment: Strong convexity gives a global minimum, maybe you meant to ask about that as opposed to strict?

Comment: yes, I meant strictly convex.